# Fetch the value of a given column in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the **value** of a single column using Eloquent:

```
MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->get(['id']); // returns [{"id":1}]

MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->select('id')->first() // returns {"id":1}
```

However, I am getting anything but the value `1`. How can get that `1`?

NOTE: *It is possible that the record with `field` of `foo` does not exist in the table!*

#### EDIT

I am ideally looking for a *single statement* that either returns the value (e.g. `1`) or fails with a `''` or `null` or other. To give you some more context, this is actually used in `Validator::make` in one of the rules:

```
'input' => 'exists:table,some_field,id,' . my_query_above...
```

#### EDIT 2

Using Adiasz's answer, I found that `MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->value('id')` does exactly what I need: returns an integer value or an empty string (when failed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel is intuitive framework... if you want value just call value() method.

```
MyModel::find(PK)->value('id');

MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->first()->value('id');
```

Comment: It fails when `first()` returns `null`: `Call to a member function value() on null` ;(

Comment: change it to firstOrFail() - that prevent errors for non-existing models

Comment: not quite an option unfortunately, I am using this for building an API... `firstOrFail` will generate HTML markup

Comment: so make IF statement like in Vikash answer... think a little!

Comment: Please see my edits, I added some important context to the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I just figured out that `MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->value('id')`  gives me exactly what I needed (int or `''` if failed)... Thanks!

Comment: This method will actually pull all of the values from the database, go through the process of hydrating the model, only for a single value to be pulled out of it. It's not particularly ideal when you want only a single value.

Comment: This is incorrect usage of value(). This will cause unexpected behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955730/laravel-value-function-not-returning-the-right-value

Comment: `MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->value('name');` worked for me. If I keep the `first()` method, I get the value in square brackets with UTF8 problems.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the Eloquent query builder, so by default, it'll return an Eloquent model with only the value you wish.

The method you're looking for is `pluck()` which exists in the normal query builder (of which the Eloquent one extends) so your code should look as follows:

```
MyModel::where('field', 'foo')->pluck('id'); // returns [1]
```

The `value()` method that is being used in the other answers is an Eloquent model method. Using that means that the framework queries the database, hydrates the model and then returns only that value. You can save yourself a few keystrokes and few CPU cycles by using `pluck()` and have it handled simply in one query.

Comment: How do I retrieve `1` from that given that the array **might potentially be empty**?

Comment: if($result) { return $result[0]; }

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8 with the help of Eloquent, you can use the following:

```
MyModel::find(PK)->getAttribute('name')
```

- *MyModel* is the model name
- *PK* is the primary-key (the row which you are looking for)
- *name* is the column of which value you want to return

note: `getAttribute()` allows you to specify a single column whereas `getAttributes()` allows you to specify an array of columns.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP7:

```
MyModel::find($id)->{$value}
```