# Laravel Value() function not returning the right value

Tags: php, laravel

This is probably the strangest bug I've ever encountered in Laravel, and I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

Basically, I'm trying to get the value of a query. In this scenario, there are 3 images. Their titles are "1st image title", "2nd image title", and "3rd image title".

Here is the relevant code:

```
public function postFav($username, $URLtitle)  {

  $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
  $userID = User::where('username', $username)->value('id');
  $image = Images::where('url_title', $URLtitle)->first();
```

Simple enough.

However, there's a problem.

If I diedump the title, like so:

```
dd($image->value('title'));
```

it always gives me the result "1st image title", the first image uploaded to the database.

So I try, rather than getting the value, I try just doing a normal diedump.

```
dd($image);
```

This is where things get weird.

[image]

That's right. dd($image) returns the correct image every time, but dd($image->value('title')) returns the first image's title.

What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try without any value method. Try this way:

```
 dd($image->title)
```

Comment: Woah. It works. It's returning the right value... why does that work? That doesn't make sense... I'm so confused

Comment: Your sql query retrieve only one row as array. That's why you can dd() or echo any field using this way - $object->fieldName . If you think my answer is helpful then please choose it as appropriate ans for your question.